# How to use flutter firebase_ml_vision plugin for live reading of characters or barcodes

Tags: flutter

Is **firebase_ml_vision** plugin supports live reading of characters or barcodes from the camera?

If no, how can I achieve this functionality?

Is it possible to use get output frames from the camera and use them with the plugin?

Comment: As of right now, there is't.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use Maurice’s MLkit demo. Both the firebase_ml_vision and camera plugins are provided in Maurice’s MLkit. [repository link](https://github.com/bparrishMines/mlkit_demo)

Check out this tweet, He builded the same thing that you want using the same repo only.
[tweet link](https://twitter.com/Samaritan101011/status/1075361931010093057)

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_camera_ml_vision which basically start from Maurice's MlKit demo but put it